# How to find sub-element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

How to find a sub-element. In below i need to select A tag inside P Tag. The error object has no attribute to click.

```
<p class="parent">
    Stack
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">overflow</a>
</p>
```

Python code

```
find = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("p.parent>a")
find.click()
```

Comment: Does this work? `.parent a`

Comment: @DanielButler same result object has no attribute to click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is you are finding `elements` and you want only one element returned. When looking for elements it returns a list.

Try this instead.

```py
find = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".parent a")
find.click()
```

Comment: In the error message did it say something about a list does not have the attribute?  I ran into this very same problem when I was first using selenium.